# When creating DOCX using DocumentFormat OpenXml is it possible to find out where are we currently on a page?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I'm creating docx file by using DocumentFormat OpenXML API, appending texts, tables, images, etc... at some point I'd like to know how much "space" (rows, pixels, whatever) I have before I reach the end of the page.

Is it possible to get this information? The page size, formatting, margins, etc, are all there - everything that's needed to calculate this is in the document.

*I do understand that the document itself doesn't deal with formatting*, how many pages are there etc, but if not from the OpenXML API, is there some other way to find this out? Maybe some dummy formatter that reads this docx and can be used to find out the 'formatting' data - where is currently the last character positioned on a page, etc... is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a "dummy formatter".  Such a thing would need to replicate Word's page layout model (including line spacing, how it hyphenates words, calculates space for the header/footer etc).  That might be relatively straightforward for simple text only documents, but for a full solution, you have tables, columns, images, text boxes etc etc to worry about.

Can you automate Word and ask it?

Comment: We've done word automation earlier, but we need this running on server and it turns out it's really not recommended to automate word in a service (we've made some workarounds but even simple stuff is really tedious to implement)... and to close this issue - I believe you're right - whoever would write such a 'formatter' wouldn't go all the way just for 'viewing' purposes - he'll build the whole deal, and sell it :). Thanks anyway!